# How is the callback function called in udp_recv in lwip?

Tags: c, udp, lwip

I am going through an example code of udp lwip [server](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/master/lib/sw_apps/lwip_udp_perf_server/src/udp_perf_server.c), and I am confused as to how the `udp_recv_perf_traffic` callback function is called from the `udp_recv` function. How does the system know that it has received a datagram? Is there a flag the udp_recv function checks?

Answer (score 0):

https://doc.ecoscentric.com/ref/lwip-api-raw-udp-recv.html

The routine udp_recv_perf_traffic() isn't *called from* upd_recv; it's registered as a callback function, meaning that udp_recv_perf_traffic() is invoked when a UDP datagram is received.

Comment: Is there a way I can know when a datagram is received or not in UDP without checking if the callback function is called or not?

Comment: I edited my answer -- the callback is only invoked when a *UDP* datagram is received. (That might answer your "not in UDP" question; I'm not entirely sure what you meant by that.) But, the bigger issue is, I'm not sure you understand the purpose of the callback. It is precisely for informing your program that the datagram has been received. In the callback (which should usually be fast (avoid printouts, etc.), you can either read the datagram, or set a global variable to inform the program that a datagram awaits, or a number of other options. Does this help?